# Regarding Outer Joins When Used In Conjunction With Inner Joins

Tags: sql

ISSUE:  I am a beginner SQL user and want to verify my understanding of LEFT OUTER JOINS (using the adventure works database).  I already understand how a simple LEFT OUTER JOIN works.  It takes the entire table on the LEFT side and matches any right values it can find, otherwise it leaves a NULL for the RIGHT side.  Where I am slightly confused is when you have a series of INNER JOINS followed by a LEFT OUTER JOIN.  So my question is for the below code, which side is the LEFT OUTER JOIN considering the LEFT side?  Is it the value after FROM:

```
FROM **Person.Person** AS Pp
```

Or is one of the INNER JOIN tables referenced?  See code below and thanks!

```
DECLARE @Date AS NVARCHAR(60)
SET @Date = '2013-01-01'

DECLARE @Date1 AS NVARCHAR(60)
SET @Date1 = '2013-12-31'

DECLARE @Date2 AS NVARCHAR(60)
SET @Date2 = '2012-01-01'

DECLARE @Date3 AS NVARCHAR(60)
SET @Date3 = '2012-12-31'


SELECT Pp.FirstName + ' ' + Pp.LastName AS 'Name', 
Ph.PhoneNumber,Em.EmailAddress, St.Name AS 'Sales Territory',

(

SELECT SUM(Soh.TotalDue) AS 'TEST'
FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader AS Soh
WHERE Soh.SalesPersonID = Pp.BusinessEntityID 

) AS 'Total Revenue',

(

((SELECT SUM(Soh.TotalDue) FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader AS Soh WHERE 
Soh.OrderDate BETWEEN @Date AND @Date1 AND Soh.SalesPersonID = 
Pp.BusinessEntityID)-
(SELECT SUM(Soh.TotalDue) FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader AS Soh  WHERE 
 Soh.OrderDate BETWEEN @Date2 AND @Date3 AND Soh.SalesPersonID = 
 Pp.BusinessEntityID))/
(SELECT SUM(Soh.TotalDue) FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader AS Soh WHERE 
Soh.OrderDate BETWEEN @Date2 AND @Date3 AND Soh.SalesPersonID = 
Pp.BusinessEntityID)

) * 100 AS 'Percent Change In Rev'
FROM Person.Person AS Pp
INNER JOIN Person.PersonPhone AS Ph
ON Pp.BusinessEntityID = Ph.BusinessEntityID
INNER JOIN Person.EmailAddress AS Em
ON Pp.BusinessEntityID = Em.BusinessEntityID
INNER JOIN Sales.SalesPerson AS Sp
ON Sp.BusinessEntityID = Pp.BusinessEntityID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Sales.SalesTerritory AS St
ON Sp.TerritoryID = St.TerritoryID
ORDER BY 'Total Revenue' DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as a LEFT OUTER JOIN.  There are only LEFT, RIGHT, INNER and FULL (OUTER) joins.

LEFT takes all values from the left side (the FROM side) and matches them with any results from the right.

A right join just does the opposite table, the one being joined as the full result set.

Inner only finds the matches.

Outer finds everything, and connects the ones it can connect.

Comment: `LEFT OUTER JOIN` is valid ANSI/ISO syntax and supported in all databases that I can readily think of.  The `OUTER` is optional, so it is often expressed as `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: I agree with Gordon, LEFT OUTER JOIN vs LEFT JOIN are the same thing.

Comment: My problem with the phrase of outer joins, is that it obfuscates the actual outer join function.  And it obfuscates LEFT JOIN syntax which is the standard.

Answer (score 0):

When you have a series of joins such as:

```
a inner join b inner join c inner join d left join e
```

Then this is treated as:

```
(((a inner join b) inner join c) inner join d) left join e
```

This semantic interpretation, not how the joins are necessarily executed.  And this interpretation is independent of the types of joins.  This is how joins are interpreted in the `FROM` clause with no parentheses.

Now, the parentheses don't help so much on *understanding*.  So, what goes on is that the initial tables are all inner joined together.  This is the set of rows for the result set.  The `left join` is then applied to this set of rows.  It is effectively:

```
(a inner join b inner join c inner join d) left join e
```

For almost all purposes, I find that inner joins followed by left joins meet my outer join needs.  I don't ever use `right join`, for instance.  Mixing inner and outer joins  in another order -- well, that just would give me a headache trying to figure out what is and is not in the result set.